# Why does function inside react-query hook fails to run on the first try?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I have custom react-query hook, that fetches current users all diary collection documents.

Inside my function I want to return array of my documents, however the
`querySnapshot.forEach...` never runs when my component mounts, instead I have to refocus on different windows to reactivate the hook for it to work.

```
function Diarytest() {
    
  const fetchUsersDiaryCollection = async () => {
    const q = query(
      collection(
        firestore,
        "currentDiary",
        auth.currentUser?.uid ?? "_STUB_",
        "days"
      )
    );
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    let fullDaysArray = [] as Day[];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log("this ran!");
      const data = doc.data() as Day;
      fullDaysArray.push(data);
    });
    return fullDaysArray;
  };

  const diaryResult = useQuery("diary", fetchUsersDiaryCollection);

  return (
    <>
      {diaryResult.data &&
        diaryResult.data.map((day) => <div>{day.dayName}</div>)}
    </>
  );
}

export default Diarytest;
```

How can I make my documents fetch automatically when my component mounts?

Comment: Where is useFirestoreQuery coming from and what does it do? This is not a hook react-query exposes

Comment: @TkDodo I have changed it to useQuery hook, but I am still not getting my data when my component mounts, but have to refocus on different browser windows in order to trigger it.